# How to tell the terraform not to destroy the existing resource conditinally

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

How to tell the terraform not to destroy the existing resource on condition

Hello I have a terraform variable which controls the creation of the resource

```
variable "apigw_key" {
  type    = string
  default = "X"
}
```

When i run the terraform apply It create the resource appropriately

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "whitelist-create" {
  parent_id   = "u8u7hy"
  path_part   = "create"
  rest_api_id = "9uumm7"
  count       = var.apigw_key == "X" ? 1 : 0
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "account-delete" {
  parent_id   = "fgty72"
  path_part   = "delete"
  rest_api_id = "9uumm7"
  count       = var.apigw_key == "Y" ? 1 : 0
}
```

The output seems to be perfect when terraform apply is run

terraform apply -var="apigw_key=X"

```
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

When i run the terraform plan on **Y** the **X** resources shows destroyed in the plan

```
variable "apigw_key" {
  type    = string
  default = "Y"
}
```

terraform plan -var="apigw_key=Y"

```
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

How to control the existing resource not to be destroyed

**Edited**  based on Marko feedback

```
variable "X" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}
```

```
variable "Y" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}
```

This is my updated resource config

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "whitelist-create" {
  parent_id   = "u8u7hy"
  path_part   = "create"
  rest_api_id = "9uumm7"
  count       = var.Y ? 1 : 0
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "account-delete" {
  parent_id   = "fgty72"
  path_part   = "delete"
  rest_api_id = "9uumm7"
  count       = var.X ? 1 : 0
}
```

**terraform apply -var X=true**

**aws_api_gateway_resource.account-delete**  will get created and maintain the state file

and when i do the following  **terraform apply -var Y=true**  it will create one resource and delete one

**My Question is how to prevent existing resource not to be deleted ?**

Comment: Well, the variable changed its value, the boolean expression changes and so does the number hence for X the first gets created for Y the second one gets created and the first one deleted. It could be done in many different ways, one of which is to have two variables, e.g. `apigw_key_delete` and `apigw_key_whitelist`.

Comment: I have changed the approach variable "whitelist-create" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}

variable "account-create" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}

 tfay -var whitelist-create=true

5 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

and then again same thing happening

Comment: Can you add the changes you made to the question along with what you want to achieve.

Comment: Have you destroyed everything prior to running apply with the changed variables? I see no reason to delete the `account-delete` API Gateway resource. Can you post the output when you run `terraform apply -var Y=true`? Also, it is a good practice to define variable values in a file instead of adding them with CLI. Unless you provide the same value every time you run `terraform apply` the count will be reset to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the behavior you're describing is desirable - if your configuration doesn't create a resource, you don't want that resource to exist. However, in some cases there might be requirements for record keeping or depreciation that prevent you from deleting it as soon as you don't need it.

If you want to conditionally create a resource, but not delete it when that condition changes, use the `prevent_destroy` lifecycle argument:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "whitelist-create" {
    parent_id   = "u8u7hy"
    path_part   = "create"
    rest_api_id = "9uumm7"
    count       = var.Y ? 1 : 0
    lifecycle {
        prevent_destroy = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I beg to disagree: if I'm not mistaken, the issue happens because variable values are provided with CLI options. If they are omitted, they will have default value which is always `false`. However, in order not to have any changes, it is enough to have them defined in a `.tfvars` file and the resource that was already created will not be destroyed.

Comment: I'm assuming the question is the result of a corner case use of the tool, and the user wants the behavior he says he wants, mainly because this isn't the best website for more fundamental questions.

Comment: @DanMonego You don't understand what the `prevent_destroy` parameters does. It fails any plan that requires that resource to be destroyed, which means that if OP puts this on their resource, their entire configuration will fail for a `destroy` operation. And this is absolutely not the wanted behavior. This (what I would dare to call) bug is tracked at https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3874 since 2015, and Hashicorp still hasn't addressed the issue at all...